# Mount overlay before starting services on Centos 8

Tags: systemd, centos-8

I'm using centos 8 OS. I need to mount overlay on boot (for example to store /var/log on a different disk) before other services started.
My initial implementation was to write a service (/etc/systemd/system/) and start it on boot

```
[Unit]
After=flash.mount

[Service]
...
ExecStart=(path to script)
...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But after I've checked running processes with lsof command, I've found that there are some processes that were started before this service and are using /var/log instead of mounted dir

I've checked some links and there is a suggestion here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554767/which-file-should-i-modify-to-mount-a-user-overlay-at-boot-time
To add script to initramfs/scripts directory

But it looks like there is no such files in centos 8. I've found a question about it without answer.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224611/how-do-i-add-modules-binaries-or-scripts-to-initramfs-in-rhel-distributions

Also I found a duplicate question with the accepted answer with a question in the first link [mount overlayfs on “/” before systemd starts](https://superuser.com/questions/1507278/mount-overlayfs-on-before-systemd-starts?newreg=d5a366c0562d4ab087363e63975623b0) And there is a suggestion to edit initramfs file. But I'm not sure how to do it on centos 8